# how can i left join and add where condition its doesn't read the where it brings all the ridedriver object?

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, symfony-3.2

How can I `LEFT` and add `WHERE` condition? 
It doesn't read the where it brings all the `ridedriver` object?

```
SELECT p 
FROM RideDriverEmployeeBundle:Ridedriver p 
LEFT JOIN Chaya3niUserBundle:Bookings b WITH b.idridedriver = p.id 
WHERE p.frequency IS NOT NULL 
  AND p.nbrplaces > 0 
  AND b.iduser != 2 
  OR b.iduser IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it is probably an issue with your `WHERE` clause. Try using parantheses with the `OR` portion of the clause.

```
SELECT p 
FROM RideDriverEmployeeBundle:Ridedriver p 
LEFT JOIN Chaya3niUserBundle:Bookings b WITH b.idridedriver = p.id 
WHERE p.frequency IS NOT NULL 
  AND p.nbrplaces > 0 
  AND (b.iduser != 2 OR b.iduser IS NULL)
```

To answer the question you asked in the comments..

> i want to select all the driverrides except the one that the user already booked in

Sounds like you just do not want the other conditions you have in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT p 
FROM RideDriverEmployeeBundle:Ridedriver p 
LEFT JOIN Chaya3niUserBundle:Bookings b WITH b.idridedriver = p.id 
WHERE b.iduser IS NULL
```

By doing a `LEFT JOIN` and then only taking records that did not exist in the joined table with `WHERE .. IS NULL`, this is doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

[image]

In your case `Ridedriver` is Table A and `Bookings` is Table B, so this will return records in `Ridedriver` that do not join to anything in `Bookings`.

Comment: ty now it works but the problem is using AND (b.iduser != 2 OR b.iduser IS NULL) or not not changing anything where it should not be the same result

Comment: i tryed this sql and it works like it shoudl be 
SELECT DISTINCT(p.id),citySource,cityDestination,b.iduser FROM ridedriver p LEFT JOIN bookings b ON b.idridedriver=p.id WHERE p.frequency IS NOT NULL AND p.nbrplaces>0 AND b.iduser!=2 or b.iduser IS NULL;

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Are you having another problem?

Comment: yeah i kinda didnd explane my prob i did the join between the two table just to filter my view i have two enties i want to get all ridedrivers except the ones that user is already on it but this request kinda miss something i dont know how to add the condition its turing to be wierd :/ i can post the entites if u want

Comment: Yeah, if you can give example data sets and what you are expecting that always helps to make a question really clear.

Comment: i want to select all the driverrides except the one that the user already booked in

Comment: The what is the purpose of the other conditions in the `WHERE` clause? (`p.frequency IS NOT NULL AND p.nbrplaces > 0  AND b.iduser != 2`)

Comment: tryin to filter rides with 0 places and if it belongs to employeeride but u can remove them cuz thzy work fine but my rpoblem is that i stated earlier